# Jasper Report Parameter Display

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, ireport

I've tried couple of options for parameter display:

```
alert_type.name --> varchar
alert_type.id --> integer
Alert_Type --> java.util.collection
```

1.a Parameter in Report Query: 
    $X{IN, alert_type.name, Alert_Type}

1.b Parameter display in Report: 
[Alert1, Alert2, ..., Alertn)

In this case selected parameters where shown correctly but I needed to change alert_type.name (varchar) to alert_type.id (integer)

2.a Parameter in Report Query: 
    $X{IN, alert_type.id, Alert_Type}

2.b Parameter display in Report: 
Report was not generated so I tried what is in number 3.

3.a Report query: 
    $X{IN, COALESCE (CAST (alert_type.id AS varchar (100))), Alert_Type}

3.b Parameter display in Report: 
[1,2,3,4....n]

Now the question is how can I in Parameter display Alert1, Alert2... instead of 1,2...? So do not want to see ID's but the Names.

Here is the relevant code that was requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Alert Report" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="94b79d03-4940-4b89-bbf7-552871a5f749">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/LTA/Alert_Report_2"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://10.5.5.59:8080/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#73B0E6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CFDBE6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#73B0E6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CFDBE6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#73B0E6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CFDBE6">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="acd41491-54fa-4316-8fe7-de309d164657">
        <parameter name="Alert_Type" class="java.util.Collection"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT
    alert.event_timestamp,
    alert_type.id,
    alert_type.name
FROM
    alert
JOIN
    alert_type ON alert.type = alert_type.id
WHERE
     $X{IN, COALESCE (CAST (alert_type.id AS varchar (100))), Alert_Type}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="event_timestamp" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Alert_Type" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    alert.event_timestamp,
    alert_type.id,
    alert_type.name
FROM
    alert
JOIN
    alert_type ON alert.type = alert_type.id
WHERE
    $X{IN, COALESCE (CAST (alert_type.id AS varchar (100))), Alert_Type}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="event_timestamp" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="84" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="673a92ae-a498-47f7-8bb2-cf09f3e08b50" x="0" y="0" width="154" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro" size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Alert Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b6c26413-0c0d-40d3-81f7-33b8f15799d8" x="599" y="33" width="83" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Creation Time:  ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
                <reportElement uuid="f5b19632-5fda-44bb-85d3-963aff9e744f" x="682" y="33" width="120" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="0d130948-71cd-490d-93cf-6f43c6ae924b" x="0" y="30" width="802" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="">
                <reportElement uuid="1c06e35e-23a6-4fd4-90a8-c88116876423" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="116" y="55" width="673" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Alert_Type}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e6d2f050-af99-4a2b-ba4a-1491365ffb53" x="0" y="55" width="109" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Selected Alert Types:  ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="177" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="277271e9-b212-446c-9be3-84bd266ce97b" key="table 3" style="table 3" x="0" y="14" width="360" height="50"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="e7fe0328-3db3-42ab-aa27-8c9ad0843710">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="21dcad58-1a5c-4d93-9c59-8346e4923544">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 3_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="4e38f6d5-e810-440d-b66e-d10284cb8cc3" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[event_timestamp]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="ffdaada2-ec5e-413f-9c67-0eba447e4581" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{event_timestamp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="dccb3cdd-5cb1-413f-9d00-24fc950a35af">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 3_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="394a428e-351d-4271-bc04-f58018ea0077" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[id]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="311b77d8-3d60-4149-8dd9-52ee5b3062c8" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="bb72b714-6cac-45a1-a5db-c5d8ebc17b02">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table 3_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="d0d4e3d7-fedf-4fc7-837e-97572d0c1a56" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 3_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="18bc66b3-228f-4d32-a764-95a72950e430" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="7dc7143d-623f-46ef-baf0-0297979eea1c" x="682" y="5" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="6c6ad707-c542-42d7-88b7-ef4a4ba4d473" x="762" y="5" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Myriad Pro"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you post your jrxml code?

Comment: @user2477868 `Now the question is how can I in Parameter display Alert1, Alert2... instead of 1,2...?` - Are you talking about printing parameter's values in generated report (output file)?

Comment: Yes,I want to print the parameter value in generated report.

Comment: jrxml code was added to original question.

Comment: Would anyone be able to help mne on this one?